# Fallo al crear archivo.a desde un Makefile compilando archivos .c

Tags: c, linux, makefile

Necesito compilar mis archivos .c a una libreria .a. El problema es que en MacOS el makefile funciona bien y en Linux da el siguiente fallo al hacer el make "Makefile:38: *** empty variable name.  Stop."

Estos son mis .c

```
 SRCS =         ft_memset.c ft_bzero.c ft_memcpy.c ft_memccpy.c ft_memmove.c\
        ft_memchr.c ft_memcmp.c ft_strlen.c ft_strlcpy.c ft_strlcat.c\
        ft_strchr.c ft_strrchr.c ft_strnstr.c ft_strncmp.c ft_atoi.c\
        ft_isalpha.c ft_isdigit.c ft_isalnum.c ft_isascii.c ft_isprint.c\
        ft_toupper.c ft_tolower.c ft_calloc.c ft_strdup.c\
        ft_substr.c ft_strjoin.c ft_strtrim.c ft_split.c ft_itoa.c\
        ft_strmapi.c ft_putchar_fd.c ft_putstr_fd.c ft_putendl_fd.c\
        ft_putnbr_fd.c\

SRCS_BONUS  = ft_lstnew.c ft_lstadd_front.c ft_lstsize.c ft_lstlast.c\
         ft_lstadd_back.c ft_lstdelone.c ft_lstclear.c ft_lstiter.c\
         ft_lstmap.c\
```

Luego las reglas de compilacion para generarme los objetos, con los flags y el compilador

```
OBJS        = ${SRCS:.c=.o}

OBJS_BONUS  = ${SRCS_BONUS:.c=.o}

NAME        = libft.a

CC          = cc

RM          = rm -f

CFLAGS      = -Wall -Wextra -Werror
```

Esta regla es la que me da el error diciendo que esta vacia cuando en MacOS compila perfectamente (Actualmente estoy con Linux Mint 19.3 Actualizado)

```
.c.o:       = 
        @${CC} ${FLAGS} -c $< -o ${<:.c=.o}
```

Y Demas

```
$(NAME):    ${OBJS}
        ar rc ${NAME} ${OBJS}
        ranlib ${NAME}

bonus:      ${OBJS} ${OBJS_BONUS}
        ar rc ${NAME} ${OBJS} ${OBJS_BONUS}
        ranlib ${NAME}

 all:       ${NAME}

 clean:
        ${RM} ${OBJS} ${OBJS_BONUS}

 fclean:        clean
        ${RM} ${NAME}

 re:            fclean bonus

 .PHONY:        clean fclean all re bonus
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error, es el '=' que colocas, puesto que al poner '=' dices que es una variable, pero lo que tiene delante no es un nombre de variable, si no el nombre de una regla .o.c : y entre este y el '=' no hay nada.

La solución sería :

```
.c.o:      ///Sin el '='//
        @${CC} ${FLAGS} -c $< -o ${<:.c=.o}
```

Para que make no muestre los comandos que se ejecutan, puedes utilizar la opcion "**-s -> --silent, --quiet**" de la forma "**make -s**"

No se porque en MacOS si te funciona.Puede ser otra versión de Make.

Comment: Ya funciona correctamente el makefile compila. En MacOS esa regla servia para que con el @ no mostrase en terminal los archivos modificados/creados/eliminados y ese es el nuevo problema, los muestra

Comment: Gracias por la información. Recuerdo haber visto esa opcion para que no mostrase nada por la salida estandar. Si lo encuentro te lo pongo aqui.

Comment: @DarkTemplar he incluido en la respuesta como evitar que make muestre los comandos por pantalla. Tambien puedes consultarlo desde un terminal con "man make"

Comment: Efectivamente con -s no hay necesidad de colocar el @ en el makefile linea por linea.